# How to Categorize JSON Data With Resulted Data Object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I was working on Categorizing the JSON object with respective to `tags`. I wanted to Display the resulted JSON Object as shown below

> **EXPECTED OUTPUT**

**Immaculate:**

[image: JsonImage] [image: JSONImage]

First Login

**Treasure**

[image: Json Image]

Treasure

I Can able to get the list of all the data in html view but Can't able to Categorize JSON Data with `tags`

**Here is my Code**

```js
var data = {
        "active_lists": 
        [{
          "id": "58b80424037940e95e7b23c6",
          "name": "First Login",
          "tags": {
              "0": "FAQ",
              "1": "immaculate"
            },
          "imageName": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/amway-bk/58b38f56037940082024af74/media/images/58a6e5c22b87b917951.png",
        },
        {
          "id": "58b402b0037940377f24af75",
          "name": "Guru",
          "tags": {
              "0": "FAQ",
              "1": "treasure"
            },
          "imageName": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/amway-bk/58b38f56037940082024af74/media/images/586b2bd2bab27924594.png",
        },
        {
          "id": "58b402b007854377f24af75",
          "name": "Guru2",
          "tags": {
              "0": "FAQ",
              "1": "immaculate"
            },
            "imageName": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/amway-bk/58b38f56037940082024af74/media/images/586b270d5cf9d689829.png",
        }]
};
    console.log(data);
    data.active_lists.forEach( function(obj) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = obj.imageName;
    img.setAttribute("class", "banner-img");
    document.getElementById("img-container").appendChild(img);
    });
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <h3 class="titletag">Earned Badges</h3>
      <div class="imagetop" id="img-container">
      <p id="badgetitle"></p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Please Help me out how to achieve the expected output.!!

Thank you.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: @Marco Principio Hi, I was getting the output as shown in the snippet.

Comment: @Rahav, what exact output you want? Because 'tags' is not a single value. It is an object.

Comment: @Laxminarayan Yes its an object. But I need to display according to tags[1]. As shown above I've  3 arrays but `tags[1] : "immaculate"` has repeated 2 times. Here `immaculate` data should be arranged in one line  `treasure` data in another line as shown in **EXPECTED OUTPUT**

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object of tags is incorrect. Last tag ("treasure") shouldn't have a comma after it.
It should be like this.

```
"tags": {
        "0": "FAQ",
        "1": "treasure"
 }
```

And What do you mean by categorizing by tags?
Do you want to loop over tags and skip "FAQs" tag and read the another tag?

If so, this is probably what you need to do -

```
var badgeTitle;
for(var key in obj.tags) {
    if(obj.tags[key] != "FAQs") {
         badgeTitle = obj.tags[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Actually, As of now i was just showing all the data under `active_lists `. But What I was looking is it should be categorized with tags. Updated the **EXPECTED OUTPUT**. Just take look.

Comment: You can loop through JSON and create another object with tags as key and images array as value. And then use it.